# "Select All" Checkbox and other features won't work in Django Admin

Tags: python, django

In my Django admin the checkbox at the top of the column of checkboxes does nothing. Usually it select/deselects all items in the list to allow for quick deletion or other actions, but I think there's something wrong with the javascript that runs that function.

It's not just in one model or one app, but across all models and all apps.

I've tried "collectstatic" and it gives me

```
0 static files copied to '/home/alex/newton/staticfiles', 276 unmodified.
```

Here's what the static part of my settings.py file looks like:

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Extra places for collectstatic to find static files.
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

CSS is working, images are working and loading normally. I don't have very much Javascript on my site, so I can't say whether or not the rest of the site is suffering Javascript issues.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

EDIT:
I've noticed that when I inspect my page in Chrome and check out the Console, I get these messages:

```
RelatedObjectLookups.js:196 Uncaught ReferenceError: grp is not defined
at RelatedObjectLookups.js:196
actions.js:154 Uncaught ReferenceError: grp is not defined
at actions.js:154
prepopulate.js:42 Uncaught ReferenceError: grp is not defined
at prepopulate.js:42
(MYURL).com/:1625 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined
at (MYURL).com/:1625
```

I think 'grp' is referencing Grappelli, an admin 'skin' I installed and uninstalled a bit ago. Seems it left behind some files or altered some things. Not sure how to clear it out without ruining some of the files I actually need.

EDIT 2: Well it seems I had the exact same files in a /static folder as well as a /staticfiles folder. Once I deleted the static folder's js scripts and everything else, it worked perfectly. Thanks so much for the help, Grimmy!

Comment: Since you run `collectstatic`.. does that mean it works with `debug = True`?

Comment: Yes, I'm still running it in debug mode, it's not in production yet.

Comment: Get any 404s in your browser console when visiting that page?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Everything else works perfectly. It's the only thing I've been able to notice as going wrong, that's the odd part.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_FINDERS is correct?

Comment: `django.contrib.admin` is the first app in `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: What exact Django version are you using? It could also be a bug.

Comment: I was using 1.10 and just upgraded to 1.11 - still have the same problem.

django.contrib.admin is the first app.

I didn't have any settings for STATICFILES_FINDERS so i explicitly entered what they have there as default, just to make sure. No change.

Thanks so much for all the troubleshooting so far.

Comment: Could be that you are overriding something? do you have an `admin/js` folder somewhere in your apps? As far as I remember it's the last app that defined a resource in `INSTALLED_APP` that counts.

Comment: I looked into what you were asking and couldn't find anything, but I think you're right with some kind of js override or some kind of issue, so I checked my console and edited my above post with what I found.

Comment: I have the same problem, and i'm running django 2.0.3